# Computing the inverse of some matrix

Tags: matrices, elementary-number-theory, inverse

Let $A(n) = (a_{i,j})_{1\le i,j \le n}$ be defined through: 
$a_{i,j} = 1, \text{ if } i \equiv 0 \mod (j)$, $0$ otherwise.
What is the inverse of $A$? Is there an "easy" formula for the inverse?
It seems that the inverse of the matrix has only entries $0,1,-1$.

Comment: any thoughts by yourself?

Comment: @Arnaldo: I edited the question

Comment: The matix is lower-diagonal, so an inverse is easy to calculate. However I'm not sure if there's a closed form.

Comment: @5xum you mean lower-triangular, presumably

Comment: Yes, of course...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** Your matrices $A(n)$ are parts of the infinite matrix $A = (A_{i,j})_{i,j\geq 1}$ with entries given by

$$A_{i,j}
= \mathbf{1}_{\{ j \mid i \}}
= \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } j \mid i \\ 0, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Then for each $n$, we would like to find the $n\times n$ matrix $B(n)$ for which $A(n)B(n) = I_d$ is true. Note that this relation is enough to guarantee that $B(n) = A(n)^{-1}$.

We accomplish this by constructing an infinite lower-triangular matrix $B = (B_{i,j})_{i,j\geq 1}$ for which the relation $AB = I$ holds. Once this is proved, the upper-leftmost $n\times n$-minor of $B$

$$B(n) = (B_{i,j})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$$

will serve as the inverse matrix of $A(n)$.

**2.** That being said, we want to solve the system of equations

$$ \forall i,j \ : \quad \sum_{d = 1}^{\infty} A_{i,d}B_{d,j} = \delta_{i,j}. $$

Plugging $A_{i,d} = \mathbf{1}_{\{ d \mid i \}}$, this reduces to

$$ \sum_{d \mid i} B_{d,j} = \delta_{i,j}. \tag{2} $$

Such $B$ is easily determined by applying the [*Möbius inversion formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) to the sequence $(B_{i,j})_{i\geq 1}$ for each fixed $j$:

$$ B_{i,j} = \sum_{d\mid i} \mu\left(\frac{i}{d}\right)\delta_{d,j} = \mu\left(\frac{i}{j}\right) \mathbf{1}_{\{j \mid i\}}
= \begin{cases}
\mu(i/j), & \text{if } j \mid i \\ 0, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} $$

The corresponding infinite matrix $B$ is lower triangular and solves $AB = I$ as desired. ////

Comment: You *derived* the solution, I only looked it up :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nice solution!

Comment: Thank you for comments!

Comment: @SangchulLee what is the meaning of the $d|i$ notation you use in $\sum_{d|j}$ ?

Comment: @Furrane, It means that $i$ is divisible by $d$. Then the sum runs over all positive integers $d$ for which $i$ is divisible by $d$, i.e., $d$ are divisors of $i$.

Answer (score 4):

Your matrix is http://oeis.org/A051731:

> Triangle read by rows: T(n,k) = 1 if k divides n, T(n,k) = 0 otherwise.

and (according to the OEIS entry) the inverse matrix is http://oeis.org/A054525:

> Triangle T(n,k): T(n,k) = mu(n/k) if k divides n, T(n,k)=0 otherwise (n >= 1, 1<=k<=n).

where `mu` is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) (which takes only the
values $-1, 0, 1$, confirming your conjecture).

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at $A_3$ :

$$A_3 = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0 \\ 1&1&0 \\ 1&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

With various methods you can obtain $A_3^{-1}$ :

$$ A_3^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ -1&1&0 \\ -1&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now there seems to be a trend here, with the $1$'s under the diagonal being turned into $-1$'s.

Let's look at $A_4$ :

$$A_4 = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0 \\ 1&1&0&0 \\ 1&0&1&0 \\1&1&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now $A_4^{-1}$ :

$$A_4^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\-1&1&0&0\\-1&0&1&0\\0&-1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now unfortunately, what we observe in $A_3$ doesn't hold true for $A_4$ so we need to lay out the equations :

Let's note $A_n = (a_{i,j})$ and $A_n^{-1}=(b_{i,j})$.

We have the following equations :

$$\forall i,j\in [1,n] : \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}\cdot b_{kj}=\delta_{ij} = \left\{\begin{matrix}0 &\text{if }i\ne j\\1&\text{if }i=j\end{matrix}\right.$$

(I don't have time to finish now, I'll come back later, feel free to try and use those equations, next step is using the $a_{ij}$ definition)

EDIT : Just saw Martin's answer, no way I would have solved this. I won't delete this answer as i think it highlights the general approach to such problems.